# Remove the white axes when slice is used in paraview

Tags: slice, paraview

I want to remove the 3D axes box (shown in white lines) around the slice shown below. Is there a way to do this?

[image: white 3D box shown around object in Paraview]

I tried all the settings in the slice settings panel. Most of them are controling the labels of the axes, however none the appearance of the axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable `Show  Plane` property in the `Slice` properties.